# Are there any benefits to using a refresh token to refresh an access token if using only one server over refreshing without one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

If my authentication/authorization/resource server is all the same server, are there any advantages to having a refresh token instead of just refreshing the access token without a refresh token once it is about to expire?

Comment: One scenario I can think of is that it adds the ability re revoke all refresh-tokens while not cutting off any actively used sessions, forcing people to login again within the expiration of your token but not ending everything right away. But if that's a scenario you might need is up to you

Comment: In addition: you could also have short living access tokens, in a sliding expiration scenario, updates (for example permissions) are quickly propagated without requiring the user to reauth explicitly and without waiting an access token to expire.